# Looking for DES algorithm tutorial

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, des

I am studying for cryptography and I somehow stuck on understanding how DES works. Because it is around for a long time there should be nice tutorials like fancy diagrams, videos etc around the net. I searched but with no luck. Has anyone spotted anything "easy-to-digest" for the brain?

Comment: About downvoting: This question was placed when such questions were acceptable in Stack Overflow. Down-voting penalises asking them with what makes sense today, which is a bit... meh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruce Schneier's Applied Cryptography is probably the funniest analysis you will find of it, but it is certainly not easy.

Comment: I must also add, because I needed initially to understand DES for a cryptography class, it's as well what each professor wants to emphasize on...
Certainly as many people pointed out it is not easy, I achieved understanding after many iterations and discussions with fellow students.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)?
It also points to the FIPS standard.

Note that modern cryptography and "easy-on-the-brain" don't necessarily go hand in hand...

I am certain there are open source implementations you could check out if that is what you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

des-3des encription decryption simulated with strings in java:

```
public class Filippakoc_Des {
static int[][] sb1={
    {14 , 4 , 13 , 1 , 2 , 15 , 11 , 8 , 3 , 10 , 6 , 12 , 5 , 9 , 0 , 7 },
    {0  , 15,  7 , 4 , 14, 2  ,  13,  1, 10,   6, 12,  11,  9,  5,  3,  8},
    {4  ,  1,  14,  8, 13,   6,   2, 11, 15,  12,  9,   7,  3, 10,  5,  0},
    {15 , 12,   8,  2,  4,   9,   1,  7,  5,  11,  3,  14, 10,  0,  6,  13}
};
 static int[][] sb2={
    {15 , 1 , 8 , 14, 6 ,  11,   3,  4, 9 , 7 ,  2, 13 , 12, 0, 5 ,  10},
    {3  , 13,  4,  7, 15,   2,   8, 14, 12,  0,  1,  10,  6, 9, 11,   5},
    {0  , 14,  7, 11, 10,   4,  13,  1, 5 ,  8, 12,   6,  9, 3,  2,  15},
    {13 , 8 , 10,  1,  3,  15,   4,  2, 11,  6,  7,  12, 0 , 5,  14,  9}
};
 static int[][] sb3={
    {10 , 0 ,  9,14,  6,    3,  15,  5, 1, 13,  12, 7 , 11,  4,   2,   8},
    {13 ,  7,  0, 9,  3,    4,   6, 10, 2,  8,   5, 14, 12, 11,  15,   1},
    {13 ,  6,  4, 9,  8,   15,   3,  0,11,  1,   2, 12,  5, 10,  14,   7},
    {1  , 10 ,13, 0,  6,    9,   8,  7, 4, 15,  14,  3, 11,  5,   2,  12}
};
   static int[][] sb4={
    { 7 , 13, 14, 3,   0,  6,   9, 10, 1, 2,  8,  5, 11, 12,  4,  15},
    {13 ,  8, 11, 5,   6, 15,   0,  3, 4, 7,  2, 12,  1, 10, 14,   9},
    {10 ,  6,  9, 0,  12, 11,   7, 13,15, 1,  3, 14,  5,  2,  8,   4},
    {3  , 15,  0, 6,  10,  1,   13, 8, 9, 4,  5, 11, 12,  7,  2,  14}
};
     static int[][] sb5={
    { 2, 12,  4,  1,  7,  10, 11, 6,  8,  5,   3, 15, 13,  0, 14,  9},
    {14, 11,  2, 12,  4,   7, 13, 1,  5,  0,  15, 10,  3,  9,  8,  6},
    {4 ,  2,  1, 11, 10,  13,  7, 8, 15,  9,  12,  5,  6,  3,  0, 14},
    {11,  8, 12, 7 ,  1,  14,  2, 13, 6, 15,   0,  9, 10,  4,  5,  3}
};
           static int[][] sb6={
    { 12, 1, 10, 15,  9,  2,  6, 8,  0,  13,   3,  4, 14,  7,  5, 11},
    {10, 15,  4,  2,  7, 12,  9, 5,  6,   1,  13, 14,  0,  11, 3,  8},
    {9 , 14, 15,  5,  2,  8, 12, 3,  7,   0,   4, 10,  1,  13,11,  6},
    {4,   3, 12, 12,  9,  5, 15, 10,11,  14,   1,  7,  6,   0, 8, 13}
};
           static int[][] sb7={
    { 4,11,  2, 14,  15, 0,  8, 13,  3,  12,  9,  7,  5, 10, 6, 1},
    {13, 0, 11,  7,  4,  9,  1, 10, 14,   3,  5, 12,  2, 15, 8,  6},
    {1 , 4, 11, 13,  12, 3, 7,  14, 10,  15,  6,  8,  0,  5, 9,  2},
    {6, 11, 13,  8,  1,  4, 10,  7,  9,   5,  0, 15, 14,  2, 3, 12}
};
           static int[][] sb8={
    {13,  2,  8,  4,   6,  15, 11,  1, 10,  9,  3,14,  5, 0, 12,  7},
    { 1, 15, 13,  8,  10,   3,  7,  4, 12,  5,  6,11,  0, 14, 9,  2},
    {7 , 11,  4,  1,   9,  12, 14,  2,  0,  6, 10,13, 15,  3, 5,  8},
    { 2,  1, 14,  7,   4,  10,  8, 13, 15, 12,  9, 0,  3,  5, 6, 11}
};

     public String Filippakoc_Des(String ptxt,String key,boolean encdes){
         //String a=String.format("%64s", Integer.toBinaryString(255)).replace(' ', '0');
         //String b="1011011111001001100001110000101110110000010001110101111101001010";
         String ipa=IPpermutation(ptxt);
         String ipb=IPpermutation(ptxt);
         String[] keys=Keygenerate(key);
         String[] rounds=new String[16];
         String cripttext="";
         if(encdes==true){
              for(int i=0;i<rounds.length;i++){
             if(i<1){
             rounds[i]=round(ipa,keys[i]);
             }else{
                 rounds[i]=round(rounds[i-1],keys[i]);
             }


            }

         cripttext=IPpermutation_(rounds[15]);
         //System.out.println(ptxt);
         //System.out.println(cripttext);
         }else{
              for(int i=rounds.length-1;i>=0;i--){
               if(i>14){
             rounds[i]=dround(ipb,keys[i]);
             }else{
                 rounds[i]=dround(rounds[i+1],keys[i]);
             }

         }
         cripttext=IPpermutation_(rounds[0]);
         //System.out.println(ptxt);
         //System.out.println(cripttext);
         }


        return cripttext;

         //String a=String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(255)).replace(' ', '0');
         //String b=String.format("%48s", Integer.toBinaryString(21)).replace(' ', '0');
         //System.out.println(functionf(a, b));
         //System.out.println(xor(a,b));
     }
     public String Filippakoc_3des(String ptxt,String key1,String key2,String key3,boolean encdes){
         String En="";
         if(encdes){
           En=Filippakoc_Des(ptxt, key1, true);
         En=En=Filippakoc_Des(En, key2, false);
          En=En=Filippakoc_Des(En, key3, true);
         }else{
             En=Filippakoc_Des(ptxt, key1, false);
         En=En=Filippakoc_Des(En, key2, true);
          En=En=Filippakoc_Des(En, key3, false);
         }

          return En;

     }
     public String round(String plain64,String keyi){

         String li=plain64.substring(0,32);
         String ri=plain64.substring(32);

         String ro=xor(li,functionf(ri,keyi));
         String lo=ri;
         String resultround=lo+ro;
         return resultround;
     }
     public String dround(String plain64,String keyi){
              String li=plain64.substring(0,32);
         String ri=plain64.substring(32);

         String lo=xor(ri,functionf(li,keyi));
         String ro=li;
         String resultround=lo+ro;
         return resultround;
     }
     public String xor(String a,String b){
         String res="";
         for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
             if(a.charAt(i)=='0' && b.charAt(i)=='0'){
                 res+='0';
             }else  if(a.charAt(i)=='0' && b.charAt(i)=='1'){
                 res+='1';
             }else  if(a.charAt(i)=='1' && b.charAt(i)=='0'){
                 res+='1';
             }else  if(a.charAt(i)=='1' && b.charAt(i)=='1'){
                 res+='0';
             }
         }
         return res;
     }
     public String sboxesrtn(int ff){
         String sb=Integer.toBinaryString(ff);
         if(ff<2){
             sb="000"+sb;
         }else if(ff<4){
             sb="00"+sb;
         }else if(ff<8){
             sb="0"+sb;
         }
         return sb;
     }
     public String functionf(String r32,String k48){
         String r48=Epermutation(r32);
         String xorout=xor(r48, k48);
         String[] splitto6=new String[8];
         splitto6[0]=xorout.substring(0,6);
         splitto6[1]=xorout.substring(6,12);
         splitto6[2]=xorout.substring(12,18);
         splitto6[3]=xorout.substring(18,24);
         splitto6[4]=xorout.substring(24,30);
         splitto6[5]=xorout.substring(30,36);
         splitto6[6]=xorout.substring(36,42);
         splitto6[7]=xorout.substring(42);
         String rnew32="";
         String row;
         String column="";
         for(int i=0;i<splitto6.length;i++){
            row=""+splitto6[i].charAt(0)+splitto6[i].charAt(5);
            column=splitto6[i].substring(1,5);
            //System.out.println(splitto6[i]+"  "+row+"  "+column);
            int irow=Integer.parseInt(row, 2);
            int icolumn=Integer.parseInt(column, 2);
            if(i==0){
                //rnew32+=Integer.toBinaryString(sb1[irow][icolumn]);
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb1[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }else if(i==1){
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb2[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }else if(i==2){
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb3[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }else if(i==3){
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb4[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }else if(i==4){
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb5[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }else if(i==5){
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb6[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }else if(i==6){
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb7[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }else if(i==7){
                rnew32+=String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(sb8[irow][icolumn])).replace(' ', '0');
            }
         }


        //System.out.println(rnew32.length());
        //System.out.println(rnew32);
        // System.out.print(splitto6[0]+"  "+splitto6[1]+"  "+splitto6[2]+"  "+splitto6[3]+"  "+splitto6[4]+"  "+splitto6[5]+"  "+splitto6[6]+"  "+splitto6[7]+"\n");
         rnew32=Ppermutation(rnew32);
         return rnew32;

     }
     public String Epermutation(String r32){
         r32=" "+r32;
         String r48=""+r32.charAt(31)+r32.charAt(1)+r32.charAt(2)+r32.charAt(3)+r32.charAt(4)+r32.charAt(5)+r32.charAt(4)+r32.charAt(5)+r32.charAt(6)+r32.charAt(7)+r32.charAt(8)+r32.charAt(9)+r32.charAt(8)+r32.charAt(9)+r32.charAt(10)+r32.charAt(11)+r32.charAt(12)+r32.charAt(13)+r32.charAt(12)+r32.charAt(13)+r32.charAt(14)+r32.charAt(15)+r32.charAt(16)+r32.charAt(17)+r32.charAt(16)+r32.charAt(17)+r32.charAt(18)+r32.charAt(19)+r32.charAt(20)+r32.charAt(21)+r32.charAt(20)+r32.charAt(21)+r32.charAt(22)+r32.charAt(23)+r32.charAt(24)+r32.charAt(25)+r32.charAt(24)+r32.charAt(25)+r32.charAt(26)+r32.charAt(27)+r32.charAt(28)+r32.charAt(29)+r32.charAt(28)+r32.charAt(29)+r32.charAt(30)+r32.charAt(31)+r32.charAt(32)+r32.charAt(1);
         return r48;
     }
     public String Ppermutation(String r32){
         r32=" "+r32;
         String r32p=""+r32.charAt(17)+r32.charAt(7)+r32.charAt(20)+r32.charAt(21)+r32.charAt(29)+r32.charAt(12)+r32.charAt(28)+r32.charAt(17)+r32.charAt(1)+r32.charAt(15)+r32.charAt(23)+r32.charAt(26)+r32.charAt(5)+r32.charAt(18)+r32.charAt(31)+r32.charAt(10)+r32.charAt(2)+r32.charAt(8)+r32.charAt(24)+r32.charAt(14)+r32.charAt(32)+r32.charAt(27)+r32.charAt(3)+r32.charAt(9)+r32.charAt(19)+r32.charAt(13)+r32.charAt(30)+r32.charAt(6)+r32.charAt(22)+r32.charAt(11)+r32.charAt(4)+r32.charAt(25);
         return r32p;
     }
      public String IPpermutation(String r64){
         r64=" "+r64;
         String r64p=""+r64.charAt(58)+r64.charAt(50)+r64.charAt(42)+ r64.charAt(34)+r64.charAt(26)+r64.charAt(18)+r64.charAt(10)+r64.charAt(2)
                 +r64.charAt(60)+r64.charAt(52)+r64.charAt(44)+r64.charAt(36)+r64.charAt(28)+r64.charAt(20)+r64.charAt(12)+r64.charAt(4)+
                 r64.charAt(62)+r64.charAt(54)+r64.charAt(46)+r64.charAt(38)+r64.charAt(30)+r64.charAt(22)+r64.charAt(14)+r64.charAt(6)+
                 r64.charAt(64)+r64.charAt(56)+r64.charAt(48)+r64.charAt(40)+r64.charAt(32)+r64.charAt(24)+r64.charAt(16)+r64.charAt(8)+
                 r64.charAt(57)+r64.charAt(49)+ r64.charAt(41)+r64.charAt(33)+r64.charAt(25)+r64.charAt(17)+r64.charAt(9)+r64.charAt(1)+
                 r64.charAt(59)+r64.charAt(51)+r64.charAt(43)+r64.charAt(35)+r64.charAt(27)+r64.charAt(19)+r64.charAt(11)+r64.charAt(3)+
                 r64.charAt(61)+r64.charAt(53)+r64.charAt(45)+r64.charAt(37)+r64.charAt(29)+r64.charAt(21)+r64.charAt(13)+r64.charAt(5)+
                 r64.charAt(63)+r64.charAt(55)+r64.charAt(47)+r64.charAt(39)+r64.charAt(31)+r64.charAt(23)+r64.charAt(15)+r64.charAt(7);
         return r64p;
     }
       public String IPpermutation_(String r64){
         r64=" "+r64;
         String r64p=""+
                 r64.charAt(40)+r64.charAt(8)+r64.charAt(48)+ r64.charAt(16)+r64.charAt(56)+r64.charAt(24)+r64.charAt(64)+r64.charAt(32)+
                 r64.charAt(39)+r64.charAt(7)+r64.charAt(47)+r64.charAt(15)+r64.charAt(55)+r64.charAt(23)+r64.charAt(63)+r64.charAt(31)+
                 r64.charAt(38)+r64.charAt(6)+r64.charAt(46)+r64.charAt(14)+r64.charAt(54)+r64.charAt(22)+r64.charAt(62)+r64.charAt(30)+
                 r64.charAt(37)+r64.charAt(5)+r64.charAt(45)+r64.charAt(13)+r64.charAt(53)+r64.charAt(21)+r64.charAt(61)+r64.charAt(29)+
                 r64.charAt(36)+r64.charAt(4)+ r64.charAt(44)+r64.charAt(12)+r64.charAt(52)+r64.charAt(20)+r64.charAt(60)+r64.charAt(28)+
                 r64.charAt(35)+r64.charAt(3)+r64.charAt(43)+r64.charAt(11)+r64.charAt(51)+r64.charAt(19)+r64.charAt(59)+r64.charAt(27)+
                 r64.charAt(34)+r64.charAt(2)+r64.charAt(42)+r64.charAt(10)+r64.charAt(50)+r64.charAt(18)+r64.charAt(58)+r64.charAt(26)+
                 r64.charAt(33)+r64.charAt(1)+r64.charAt(41)+r64.charAt(9)+r64.charAt(49)+r64.charAt(17)+r64.charAt(57)+r64.charAt(25);
         return r64p;
     }
     public String[] Keygenerate(String key){
    String[] keys=new String[16];
    String key56=pc_1(key);
    String lkey28=key56.substring(0,28);
    String rkey28=key56.substring(28);
      for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            if(i==0 || i==1 || i==8 || i==15){
                lkey28=Lbitrotate(lkey28, 1);
                rkey28=Lbitrotate(rkey28, 1);
                keys[i]=pc_2(lkey28+rkey28);
            }else{
                lkey28=Lbitrotate(lkey28, 2);
                rkey28=Lbitrotate(rkey28, 2);
                keys[i]=pc_2(lkey28+rkey28);
            }
        }

    return keys;

}
public String pc_1(String key){
    String key56="";
    key56=""+key.charAt(56)+key.charAt(48)+key.charAt(40)+key.charAt(32)+key.charAt(24)+key.charAt(16)+key.charAt(8)+key.charAt(0)+key.charAt(57)+key.charAt(49)+key.charAt(41)+key.charAt(33)+key.charAt(25)+key.charAt(17)+key.charAt(9)+key.charAt(1)+key.charAt(58)+key.charAt(50)+key.charAt(42)+key.charAt(34)+key.charAt(26)+key.charAt(18)+key.charAt(10)+key.charAt(2)+key.charAt(59)+key.charAt(51)+key.charAt(43)+key.charAt(35)+key.charAt(62)+key.charAt(54)+key.charAt(46)+key.charAt(38)+key.charAt(30)+key.charAt(23)+key.charAt(14)+key.charAt(6)+key.charAt(61)+key.charAt(53)+key.charAt(45)+key.charAt(37)+key.charAt(29)+key.charAt(21)+key.charAt(13)+key.charAt(5)+key.charAt(60)+key.charAt(52)+key.charAt(44)+key.charAt(36)+key.charAt(28)+key.charAt(20)+key.charAt(12)+key.charAt(4)+key.charAt(27)+key.charAt(19)+key.charAt(11)+key.charAt(3);
    return key56;
}
   public String pc_2(String key){
    String key48="";
    key48=""+key.charAt(13)+key.charAt(16)+key.charAt(10)+key.charAt(23)+key.charAt(0)+key.charAt(4)+key.charAt(2)+key.charAt(27)+key.charAt(14)+key.charAt(5)+key.charAt(20)+key.charAt(9)+key.charAt(22)+key.charAt(18)+key.charAt(11)+key.charAt(3)+key.charAt(25)+key.charAt(7)+key.charAt(15)+key.charAt(6)+key.charAt(26)+key.charAt(19)+key.charAt(12)+key.charAt(1)+key.charAt(40)+key.charAt(51)+key.charAt(30)+key.charAt(36)+key.charAt(46)+key.charAt(54)+key.charAt(29)+key.charAt(39)+key.charAt(50)+key.charAt(44)+key.charAt(32)+key.charAt(47)+key.charAt(43)+key.charAt(48)+key.charAt(38)+key.charAt(55)+key.charAt(33)+key.charAt(52)+key.charAt(45)+key.charAt(41)+key.charAt(49)+key.charAt(35)+key.charAt(28)+key.charAt(31);
    return key48;
}


  public String Lbitrotate(String bin,int times){
   String binary=bin;
   String binary2="";
   String binarynew="";
   for(int i=0;i<times;i++){
       if(i<1){
       binary2=binary.substring(1)+binary.charAt(0);
       }else{
           binary2=binarynew.substring(1)+binarynew.charAt(0);
       }
       binarynew=binary2;

   }
   return binary2;
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

[The DES Algorithm Illustrated](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~kant/teaching/hess/krypto-ws2006/des.htm) is the best simple summary (easy to digest) of DES I have seen.

As for an actual picture see [How DES Works](http://dwm.cc/gallery2/v/UCF/How+DES+Works.png.html) or a [Mirror of How DES Works](http://web.archive.org/web/20130119234315/http://dwm.cc/gallery2/v/UCF/How+DES+Works.png.html)

For AES there is [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html).

Comment: Loved the AES comic (will read it when I find time), "How DES works" gave me a 403, "The DES..." is actually straightforward and what I needed at that time.

Comment: I checked fist two links and they are not working. Can anyone give the updated link? -thanks.

Comment: Updated the first link and the second link works here

Comment: How DES Works is not working. Other two links are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked wikipedia, seems that I needed more. I also think that Schneier's book is perfect, I have it back home and could not transport it to where I study :-( shame....
Nobody said this was going to be easy perhaps I should just read it many times and write it down on paper until it gets stuck to my brain (or have Applied Cryptography posted).
 Thanks for the very quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the more repetitions I do the better it gets! Also found out the hard way, that doing it day after day helps more than all-in-once. At least I could get a copy of Schneier's book which helps a lot.
Writing my own is not an option since it is a new algorithm each week, but it is a very interesting, helpful (and obvious sometimes) idea.
It has not to do with DES, you convinced me to learn Python :-)

Comment: Funny - that's the same thing with DES - they usually have three repetitions nowadays ;-)